# Use Where condition instead of aggregate function with group by

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have as table called calendar table, Which have columns like year, month, week, date, and day. day field have values like 1,2,....7.

I want to create time span from it. like one span from Monday to Tuesday(12:00), Tuesday(12:00) to Wednesday(17:00). Within a week

For this I am writing a query like

```
SELECT 
    year, 
    week, 
    (SELECT date WHERE day = 1) AS st_date,
    (SELECT date WHERE day = 2) AS end_date 
FROM calendar 
GROUP BY year, week
```

I know above syntax is incorrect, Please tell if any possible syntax  is there to solve this problem?

Actual table definition is in Japanese so that I have replaced it with English column names. This is a calendar table that is different then our regular calendar

In a registration tool I want to create time period for user within which user can register not out of them.

My original table like:

```
Date        Year    Month  Week   Day
--------------------------------------------
2013/06/19   34      06     44    3
2013/06/21   34      07     44    5
2013/06/24   34      07     45    1 
2013/06/25   34      07     45    2
2013/06/26   34      07     45    3
```

I like to get output as

```
Year    Week    A_reg_range_st             A_reg_range_end        B_reg_range_st             B_reg_range_end
-----------------------------------------------
34      45      2013/06/24 00:00:00      2013/06/25 12:00:00        2013/06/25 12:00:00      2013/06/26 17:00:00
```

Comment: Please provide the real table definitions and some sample data to fill them, and show the desired results. It's kind of hard to tell exactly what you want, exactly how the data is defined, etc.

Comment: This is called "pivot". Search for the tag here at SO and have a look at the "crosstab" function in the "tablefunc" module in Postgres: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    year, 
    week, 
    CASE WHEN (day = 1) THEN date  AS st_date,
    CASE WHEN (day = 2) THEN date  AS end_date
FROM calendar 
GROUP BY year, week
```

Comment: Not working... It is asking to set day and date group by. And I cannot set day as group by I want to find value on its condition...